# How to keep wrapped text in SVG when loaded into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, svg

I have an SVG that contains a graph where the y-axis title is wrapped to two lines. The upper line is the parameter ("Parameter") and the lower line is the units ("(units)").

When I load the SVG into a template in QGIS, the y-axis title is unwrapped, so that the parameter and units are on one line. I would like the axis title to remain wrapped so that the y-axis is two lines.

In other words, the title looks like this:

**In the SVG:**

> Parameter
> (units)

**When the SVG is loaded into a QGIS template:**

> Parameter (units)

The SVG is generated with python, where the y-axis title is set as follows:

```
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Parameter <br> (units)",
                 titlefont=(dict(family="Arial", size =20)),
                 mirror=True,
                 showline=True,
                 linecolor='#000',
                 ticks='outside',
                 tickcolor='#000',
                 row=4, col=1,
                 showgrid=True,
                 gridwidth=1,
                 gridcolor='Gray')
```

Anyone have insight of what I may be doing wrong, or know how I can keep the text wrapped when it's loaded into QGIS?

Comment: Did you try `"Parameter \n (units)"`?

Comment: Yes I tried that too! It showed up as blank and didn't wrap the text.